# cgicc: uploading large files?

Tags: file, upload, cgi

I'm writing a CGI application in C++ using cgicc, running on an embedded device. Now I came to the point where it is required to upload a large file to the device (the firmware package for updating). Now I realize 2 problems:

1.) The web server (currently lighttpd) stores the file in an temporary file before starting the CGI application.

2.) cgicc tries to load the complete data into an allocated memory before continuing.

Point 1.) is another problem, more importand for now is point 2.). Is there a way to tell cgicc to read the file piece by piece instead at once? Otherwise I run into OOM trouble.

Any other suggestion which can help are welcome!

Thanx, Andi